# Angular PrimeNG Autocomplete: Displaying multiple fields?

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, angular5, primeng

Suppose we have this scenario:

```
<p-autoComplete dataKey="id" field="make" emptyMessage="{{'NoDataFound' | translate}}"
    [delay]="0" [suggestions]="vehicles" [minLength]="0" appendTo="body"
    (completeMethod)="searchVehicles($event)" (onSelect)="on($event)">
    <ng-template let-vehicle pTemplate="item">
      {{vehicle.make}} {{vehicle.model}}
    </ng-template>
</p-autoComplete>
```

with the controller:

```
export class AutoCompleteDemo {

    selectedVehicle: Vehicle;

    vehicles: Vehicle[];

    searchVehicles(event) {
        this.vehiclelookupservice.getResults(event.query).then(data => {
            this.vehicles= data;
        });
    }
}
```

and the `Vehicle` object is of structure:

```
{
    id: int,
    make: string,
    model: string
}
```

The `field` attribute is used to display the selected object attribute (in this case `make`). How do I display the selected object to display `make + " " + vehicle`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add a `label` property to your `Vehicle` object and then, fill it with the concatenation of other fields from this object.

Something like:

```
this.vehiclelookupservice.getResults(event.query).then(data => {
    this.vehicles = data;
    this.vehicles.foreach(item => item.label = item.make + " " + item.vehicle);
});
```

Then, replace `field="make"` with `field="label"` should do the trick.

Comment: I used the `forEach` method as `map` didn't really return a result that I expected.

Comment: The `forEach` function is a `void` function. One way is to assign `data` to vehicles` and then do a `forEach` on `vehicles`.